# Can I have tfs running without logging in?

Tags: tfs

I have a tfs instance that is using the admin account on the server.
The problem comes when I want to connectwithout logging into the server : the service doesn't run if the admin is not logged in.
How can I solve this matter? I would like the service to run at computer startup (not user login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "connect to" could you clarify a little? Tfs requires that a service account is created which runs the associated tfs services. Provided that tfs is installed correctly and the tfs services are set to automatic, there should be no need to login to the tfs server to perform normal tfs operations.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess it's a configuration problem !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your server is not installed properly. Please refer to the installation guide for your version of TFS:

- [TFS
  2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29035)
- [TFS
  2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24337)
- [TFS
  2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15743)

In all versions, the service account for TFS should **not** be an administrator.